# Formula to show how much people owe each other for gifts purchased?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to have a formula in excel that will show how much people owe each other for buying Christmas presents. I have a table that looks like this

| Larry | John | Chris |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $10 | $15 | $50 |
| $10 | $20 | $15 |
| **$20** | **$35** | **$65** |

The bold is the total each person has spent. I can do a formula that sums all of those numbers and divides it by 3 to find out how much each person owes, but how would I create a formula that would show who owes who?

In this scenario the average cost per person is $40. Chris would be owed $15 from Larry and John would be owed $5 from Larry. How would you write a formula that would show how much each person owes another person based on the changes in price?

I would like for it to show how much Larry owes each person, but if the numbers change and Larry drops $100 on presents, I'd like the formula to adjust and show how much John and Chris would owe Larry and how much John would owe Chris. Can someone help me with this?

I tried to do =sum(A3:C3)/3 on D3 then =D3-A3, =D3-B3, and =D3-C3 which would show the amount each person owes or is owed. It shows that Chris is negative $15 which means he is owed that much and that Larry owes $20, but it only shows that in general and doesn't show how to disperse it to each person.

Comment: If there will always be three people, it's doable. But if there are more than three, with multiple "overs" and "unders", there could be multiple solutions. A simpler method would just have the "unders" adding to a pot, and the "overs" withdrawing from the same pot.

Comment: Your table is not explaining what money went to whom